# SetWindowsHookEx HCBT_CREATEWND GetWindowText

Tags: winapi, setwindowshookex

Anyboby knows how to get text of a created window? I set hook on `CreateWindow`, but `GetWindowText` returns empty string.

```
hCBTHook = SetWindowsHookEx(WH_CBT, (HOOKPROC) &CBTHook, g_appInstance, 0);

LRESULT CALLBACK CBTHook(int nCode, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
     if(nCode == HCBT_CREATEWND)
     {
          HWND hwnd = (HWND)wParam;
          CHAR buf[256];
          GetWindowText(hwnd, buf, 256);
     }

     return CallNextHookEx(hCBTHook, nCode, wParam, lParam);
}
```

Comment: Accessiblility hooks work much better for this sort of thing.

Answer (score 2):

["The system calls the hook procedure before sending the WM_CREATE or WM_NCCREATE message to the window."](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644977%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

The window may not have text yet, your callback is invoked very early in the process of window creation. The name of the window gets passed in as part of the `CREATESTRUCT` message sent with `WM_CREATE` which would be the earliest the window could do something about having text. Even to hard code something, it would have to be in `WM_NCCREATE`, which still hasn't happened yet when your callback is called.

*However*, the callback itself also gets passed the the `CREATESTRUCT`. If the name that was passed to `CreateWindow` is what you are after, that's [available](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644962%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) to you as well.